# Visiting the Ngong Ping 360 cable car on an evening layover in Hong Kong International Airport?

Tags: layovers, hong-kong, hkg, gondolas-and-cable-cars

Based on the [How to leave Hong Kong International Airport by foot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/35351/26) question, I know that leaving Hong Kong International Airport on foot during a layover can be done but isn't easy. However, from an answer there, I've discovered the [Wikivoyage page on Lantau Island](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hong_Kong/Lantau), and specifically the [cable car up the mountain](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hong_Kong/Lantau#By_cable_car).

Assuming my flight is on time, I'll have a 6 hour layover in the airport on a Saturday evening (roughly 6pm to midnight). I could just hop on the express train into the city, but I've spent a few days there before, so I was wondering about doing something different. The Ngong Ping 360 cable car looked interesting and nearby, so I was wondering about that.

However, the [Wikivoyage page mentions potentially long lines](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hong_Kong/Lantau#By_cable_car), which makes me worry that by the time I've got out and got there, I might not have time. I'm also not sure if it's open late, and how good the views are at night.

That leads me to wonder if I can visit there. Specifically, on a 6 hour layover, is there enough time to get to the cable car, queue, go up and get back? Can you get there and back in that time by public transport? Is it open late enough? Are the views ok at night?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google will find the [opening hours](http://www.np360.com.hk/en/visitors-information/np360-opening-hours.html) and tell you that it closes at 6.30pm

At other times the trip is possible in that amount of time, but busyness depends on time and season.

You can reach the monastery and the Big Buddha without going up the cable car, but I don't know how long it takes to drive there.

Answer (score 4):

Ngong Ping 360 opens at [10am-6pm on weekdays, and 9am-630pm on weekends and public holidays](http://www.np360.com.hk/en/visitors-information/np360-opening-hours.html). It will extend services hours to 7pm on weekends and holidays in July and August. Please note it will close on Scheduled Servicing Days. The closest one (at the time of writing, prior to any revisions) is from the 7th to the 24th of September. The trip lasts around 30 mins but the queue may take more than an hour, and will usually be longer on weekends, Sunday, holidays, and school holiday periods (summer, Easter, Christmas and lunar new year).

There are [some suggested itineraries](http://www.np360.com.hk/en/visitors-information/np360-itinerary.html) from Ngong Ping 360 which require at least 4 hours.

Instead of Ngong Ping 360 you can travel by bus no. 23 operated by New Lantau Bus Company, departing from Tung Chung. Google the bus company to find the timetable and fares. The trip lasts for one hour but the road condition is not good.

Check [here](http://www.newlantaobus.com/road_23.htm) for timetable and fare.

Additional information:

1. Due to the fact that you are arriving at 6pm, most tourist spots in Ngong Ping will be closed. I would advise that you stay in the airport.**
2. The only road (Tung Chung Road) to Ngong Ping and south Lantau Island has limited access. You cannot drive / rent private cars(including uber) through it, but taxis will be fine.