# Is it possible to walk between Kowloon and Hong Kong Island?

Tags: hong-kong, walking

I have a 5 hours transit today at Hong Kong Airport, and so I decided to visit Kowloon/Mongkok. However, I also want to enjoy Hong Kong Station. I don't have HKD in hand so I cannot take a train between the two station, although I can take Airport Express which can be purchasable via credit card.

In this case, can you still enjoy both places by walking across, possibly via a submarine tunnel, which I think a bus/train uses?

Comment: Related: [How to leave Hong Kong International Airport by foot](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/35351/3221)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't get a small amount of HKD, either from an ATM or by exchanging some of another currency, even at a bad rate? It's irritating that you have to (and irritating that you can't buy an Octopus with a credit card apparently), but it would do the job, and you could always spend any leftover cash on snacks for the flight or similar.

Comment: @ZachLipton I don't have any single money, seriously. And my card isn't avaiable in ATM, either. I usually almost always go with a credit card.

Comment: I would seriously avoid traveling to MK during a 5 hour transit. You would expect travel time to and from MK to be approx 1 hour. For international flights you NEED to be at the airport 2 hours before the flight, giving you approx 1 hour in MK. MK is not an easy place to navigate at the best of times.

Comment: I would advise you stay close to Hong Kong MTR or Kowloon MTR for safety. Hong Kong MTR is close to an area (imaginatively) named Central. There should be enough for you to do around there.

Comment: Can't you buy tickets with your credit/debit card without HKD?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, no way to walk from Kowloon to Hong Kong island, there are several ferries to cross the harbour, but none of them is free.

There is no tunnel you can walk through either, just motor traffic.